# Display order of a stacked line chart

Tags: python, stacked-chart, z-order

I am using stacked line plots that sometimes have 0 values, and the default plot puts the color of the zero line on top of the actual increasing line.

Is there any way to swap the zorder of a stacked line plot?

Please see the below simple example:

`pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,0,3]],columns=["A","B","C"]).plot(stacked=True)`

[image]

Comment: I want to see the reason for the increase for example x=1,2,3 is due to A(Blue) not B(Orange), while not using Fill area as I am mixing with a stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem for myself by replicating what stacked=True does in background using cumsum directly.

`data = [[0,1,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,0,3]]`

`pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["A","B","C"]).cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:,::-1].plot()`

[image]